# Keynote Remote Broken on OS X 10.10.3

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, keynote, ad-hoc

**Update**: I found a workaround. See below.

I have an iPhone 6 running iOS 8.3 and a rMBP running OS X 10.10.3.

Both machines have the latest version of Apple's Keynote app installed.

In the past, (i.e. on Mavericks) I could create an ad-hoc wireless network from my mac, connect to it using my iPhone, and control the presentation using Apple's Keynote app.

Unfortunately, with the advent of Yosemite, I find that the iOS Keynote app is now ridiculously flaky at connecting to Keynote through an ad-hoc network.

Any suggestions/fixes to this problem?

Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: Have you been experiencing any of Yosemite's other networking issues? If so, then that could be your issue and [your salvation could come at the hands of the upcoming OS X 10.10.4](http://9to5mac.com/2015/05/26/apple-drops-discoveryd-in-latest-os-x-beta-following-months-of-complaints-about-network-issues-with-yosemite/).

Comment: Despite doing a clean install of Yosemite, I've had plenty of networking issues. However, the only ones that are left depend on the interference between wifi and bluetooth. Most of the other stuff has been solved by trashing the SystemConfigurations folder in /Library/Preferences and by deleting Bluetooth BUN/PAN from network devices. I have a feeling it's a discoveryd issue. 10.10.4 can't come too soon. I have two presentations coming next week. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I can now positively confirm that this is a discoveryd issue.

Here's a workaround to get keynote remote working over an ad-hoc network.

1) Put iPhone (or iPad) into airplane mode and turn on wifi through control center.

2) Create your ad-hoc network on the Mac.

3) Open Terminal and execute the following commands (one-by-one):

```
sudo killall discoveryd

sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache;sudo discoveryutil udnsflushcaches;say flushed

sudo ifconfig awdl0 down
```

4) Open wifi settings on the iPhone/iPad and connect to your Mac's ad-hoc network.

5) Open Keynote app on Mac and iDevice.

6) Press the little "Play" button on the iOS keynote app.

7) It should, after a few seconds of scanning, give you a landing screen with the large green "Play" button on it.

That's it! I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

If you think it's a discoveryd issue and 10.10.4 can't come too soon, might as well make it come now! Go to [this Apple link](https://appleseed.apple.com/sp/betaprogram) and sign up for the public beta program, where you'll be given a link to download a piece of software that'll get the App Store to pick up beta updates. Take a backup of everything, install Beta Access Utility, and then install and enjoy a discoveryd-free Yosemite!

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestion! I will install 10.10.4 beta in the next day or so. I was really happy to hear that mDNSresponder is coming back. In the interim, I've actually found a  wrkaround (see below).